# Sync Services Ado.net SyncSchema

Tags: service, ado.net, synchronization

I'm trying to build a custom ServerSyncProvider 
right now. I'm trying to understand the GetScema Method.

I'm trying to build a dataSet and associate it to SyncSchema class
one of my table columns is a `nvarchar(50)`.
Here is what I'm doing this:

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.ColumnName = "Name";
column.DataType = typeof(String);
column.MaxLength = 55;
table.Columns.Add(column);
```

But it turns out that on my client side, this column becomes `nvarchar(1)`
any idea?

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
column.ExtendedProperties.Add("ColumnLength", 50);
```